# James - mail server configuration help needed

Tags: email-server

I am trying to setup James mail server on a linux machine. The linux machine has public static ip address assigned.

I installed James and added in the config.xml added the servername as mydomain.com.

In the DNS for mydomain.com, I have created a A-record, say mx.mydomain.com, which corresponds to the ipaddress of the above mail server machine. Then added mx.mydomain.com as MX record for mydomain.com.

In James, I have created a new user test. Then from gmail, I sent a mail to test@mydomain.com. The mail is not received back and it didn't even bounce back.

The linux machine is behind a firewall with only 22, 80, 8080 ports open for external network.

My question here is, Do I require do open any other ports on the firewall so that the mail I send from gmail arrives to James? If it's not the port problem, any views on solving this issue?

I don't want to send mails from this server. It's only for receiving the mails.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP Port for Mail transfer is 25, and 465 for SMTPS (ssl).

Comment: I know SMTP port 25 should be opened for sending a mail. Should it be opened for receiving a mail as well?

Comment: Found that STMP port 25 should be open for receiving the mail from remote server as well. Once the port 25 is opened, I started receiving the mails.